# MVC Action Filter in IIS 7.5+ modifying response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, action-filter

I have a MVC action filter that I use to validate my models that is giving me different responses on different versions of IIS.  Here is the code for the action filter.

```
    public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData;
        var modelStateErrors = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Keys.SelectMany(key => filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors);
        string errorMessage;

        if (modelStateErrors.Count() > 0)
        {
            ModelError error = modelStateErrors.FirstOrDefault();

            if (error.ErrorMessage.IsNotNullOrEmpty())
            {
                errorMessage = error.ErrorMessage;
            }
            else if (error.Exception != null)
            {
                errorMessage = error.Exception.Message;
            }
            else
            {
                errorMessage = Messages.UNKNOWN_VALIDATION_ERROR;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = Messages.UNKNOWN_VALIDATION_ERROR;
        }

        if (!viewData.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                filterContext.Result = new ContentResult { Content = errorMessage, ContentType = "text/plain" };
            }
            else
            {
                var controller = filterContext.Controller as WMSControllerBase;
                if (controller != null)
                {
                    controller.DisplayWarningMessage(errorMessage);
                }

                foreach (var param in filterContext.ActionParameters)
                {
                    if (param.Key.ToLower() == "model" || param.Value is ViewModelBase)
                    {
                        viewData.Model = param.Value;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (viewData.Model is ViewModelBase)
                {
                    (viewData.Model as ViewModelBase).RebuildModel();
                }

                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewData = viewData
                };
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

On an IIS 7.0 server the action filter works as intended and will produce responses like the following for AJAX calls.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 21:40:36 GMT
Content-Length: 47

The error message I want the end user to see.
```

However running on IIS 7.5 or later I get responses like the following.  Apparently IIS or MVC decides to replace my response body with "Bad Request" and sets the type to text/html.  Wondering what is going here, why would it modify the response like this?

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 08 Oct 2013 21:50:02 GMT
Content-Length: 11

Bad Request
```

Comment: Never mind, figured it out.  Either one of the following two solutions fixes the issue.  Include the following line of code:
filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
Or adding the following setting to the system.webServer node in web.config:
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

Comment: Let me add how stupid I think this functionality is on Microsoft's part.  Why don't they just get out of the developers way so we don't waste hours trying to figure out why their technology is taking control?

Comment: Wow, just found this after wasting 2 days rewriting my entire implementation.  Running IIS 10 locally was working fine but our test site is running 7.5 and applying this horrible silent manipulation. Didn't really need another reason to dislike IIS.